# Multiple builds and blackberry app world

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

i have two build of same application 
1. for touch screen
2. for non-touch screen

So how to manage these two builds on blackberry app world?
I have to upload both builds?

if i have uploaded both builds, how user will manage to download the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can upload multiple builds to App World and target each one to a specific OS and/or device list.

Comment: Hello Marc i once found a pdf that indicates how to create release build which i lost.. can u point me to any link that describes the procedure. thank u

Comment: Was there any document you found? I need to verify this for a client.

Comment: I'm not sure - I was just answering based on my experience using the Vendor Portal.